# Привет друзья! Помогите перевернуть массив String [] без использования java.util.Arrays

Tags: java

В этом методе нужно вернуть перевёрнутый массив String []. Подскажите что я делаю не так для переворота массива?

```
public static String[] reverseArray(String[] arr) {

       String [] reverse = new String[arr.length];

        for (int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            reverse[i] = arr[i];
        }

        return reverse;
    }
```

Comment: Прежде всего неправильно, что вы в вопрос вставляете картинку. Никому не хочется код набирать руками.

Comment: Прошу прощения, исправил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А вообще вы не переворачиваете массив. Вы его копируете начиная с конца `reverse[i] = arr[i]`. Т.е. просто поэлементное копирование.У вас `arr[]` должен двигаться с конца,  а `reverse[]` - c начала. Как-то так

```
int len = arr.length - 1;
for(int i = len; i>=0; i--)
    reverse[len - i] = arr[i];
```

Comment: Навёл на мысль, огромное спасибо тебе.